# Convert MemoryStream to Array C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have implemented a code block in order to convert Stream into Byte Array. And code snippet is shown below. But unfortunately, it gives OutOfMemory Exception while converting MemoryStream to Array (return newDocument.ToArray();). please could someone help me with this?

```
public byte[] MergeToBytes()
{
    using (var processor = new PdfDocumentProcessor())
    {
        AppendStreamsToDocumentProcessor(processor);
        using (var newDocument = new MemoryStream())
        {
            processor.SaveDocument(newDocument);
            return newDocument.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

public Stream MergeToStream()
{
    return new MemoryStream(MergeToBytes());        
}
```

Comment: I don't really get it: Why do you convert to an array? It seems what you want is a Stream anyway ( from `MergeToStream`) ?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly: how big is the document? if it is too big for the `byte[]` limit: you're going to have to use a different approach.

However, a `MemoryStream` is *already* backed by an (oversized) array; you can get this simply using `newDocument.TryGetBuffer(out var buffer)`, and noting that you **must** restrict yourself to the portion of the `.Array` indicated by `.Offset` (usually, but not always, zero) and `.Count` (the number of bytes that should be considered "live"). Note that `TryGetBuffer` *can* return `false`, but not in the `new MemoryStream()` scenario.

If is also interesting that you're converting a `MemoryStream` to a `byte[]` and then back to a `MemoryStream`. An alternative here would just have been to set the `Position` back to `0`, i.e. rewind it. So:

```cs
public Stream MergeToStream()
{
    using var processor = new PdfDocumentProcessor();
    AppendStreamsToDocumentProcessor(processor);
    var newDocument = new MemoryStream();
    processor.SaveDocument(newDocument);
    newDocument.Position = 0;
    return newDocument;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The purpose of this behind is that I'm going to preview multiple documents (some documents contain large-size images). and from the above code block just trying to append each document stream together. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately gave this exception (Input data is not recognized as valid pdf.) if you don't mind could you please bit explain this one -> newDocument.Position = 0;

Comment: @John_sl I don't know your age, but: are you familiar with the concept of cassette tapes? you can think of `MemoryStream` as a cassette tape; when the PDF writes to it, it is rolling forwards, and it *leaves it at the end*. If you want to *read* what you just wrote, you need to rewind the position back to the start, which is what `Position = 0` does; now, something else can read from it, and should get the same bytes back again. `MemoryStream` does not maintain separate "read" and "write" positions - there's just "the current position".